# header('Content-Type: image/jpeg') doesn't work with Firefox

Tags: php, content-type

i try to see a Preview of imagefilter() on my webpage.
For this i use a secondary page call "image_effect.php".
This is the code:

```
<?php
$dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Sviluppare siti web con PHP6, Apache, MySQL\Vari ed Esercizi\images';

if(isset($_GET['id']) && ctype_digit($_GET['id']) && file_exists($dir . '/' . $_GET['id'] . '.jpg')) {
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($dir . '/' . $_GET['id'] . '.jpg');
} else {
    die("Invalid image specified");
}

$effect = (isset($_GET['e'])) ? $_GET['e'] : -1;
switch ($effect) {
    case IMG_FILTER_NEGATE:
        imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);
        break;
    case IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE:
        imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
        break;
    case IMG_FILTER_EMBOSS:
        imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_EMBOSS);
        break;
    case IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR:
        imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
        break;
}

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image, '', 100);
?>
```

Obviously with the page image_effect.php i could see the effect without override the image saved in "images".

The directory `$dir` is correct and the name of file is `$_GET['id'].jpg`.
If i use Preview function on my first page i couldn't see the image, if i directly open image_effect.php this is the result:

```
L’immagine “http://localhost/Sviluppare%20siti%20web%20con%20PHP6,%20Apache,%20MySQL/Vari%20ed%20Esercizi/image_effect.php?id=1&e=1” non può essere visualizzata poiché contiene degli errori.
```

Instead, if i save image with effect without show the preview i could see the image correctly.

This is the code for show the image on my first page:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submit'] == 'Upload' || $_POST['submit'] == 'Save') {
    $imagename = 'images/' . $image_id . '.jpg';
} else {
    $imagename = 'image_effect.php?id=' . $image_id . '&e=' . $_POST['effect'];
}
?>
<img src="<?php echo $imagename; ?>" style="float: left;">
```

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved.
The problem is the function

```
imagejpeg($image, '', 100);
```

The correct form is

```
imagejpeg($image);
```

or

```
imagejpeg($image, NULL, 100);
```

If i use this it works fine.

[This](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) and [this](https://www.php.net/imagejpeg) is the documentation of side function.

Comment: So instead of returning the stream to the browser you returned it to the file and you still don't know why it couldn't work?